# May Jews attach or detach cup handles on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, orach-chaim, boneh-soter

According to Halacha is it permitted for Jews to attach or detach [detachable cup handles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0771RGHK3) on Shabbat or no? Would it fall into any prohibited melacha or something else?

Comment: You mean because we may come to use the cupholder in our car or the [cd drive](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/Cd_reader_used_as_a_cup_holder.jpg/800px-Cd_reader_used_as_a_cup_holder.jpg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears permitted in your case since the cup holder is only loosely connected to the cup. See Rambam MT [Shabbat 22:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sabbath.22.26?lang=bi&with=Shulchan%20Arukh,%20Orach%20Chayim&lang2=en)

> A candelabrum made up of separate pieces may not be reassembled on the
> Sabbath, nor may a chair or a table made up of pieces be
> reconstructed, for this resembles building. If, however, one does
> reassemble these objects, one is not liable, since [the forbidden
> labors] of building and demolishing do not apply regarding utensils.
> **If [the parts of such a utensil] remain loosely put together, one may
> [complete] its assembly.**

Shulchan Aruch ([OC 313:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.313.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) writes the same if the cup holder is not tightly assembled (which seems the case in your example)

> It is permitted to assemble and separate on Shabbos parts of a cup
> made of different pieces. However, there is an opinion that says that
> a cup has the same rule as the bed. Rema: If usually tightened, it is
> forbidden to reassemble even loosely.

See also Magen Avraham which permits attaching covers to cups.

This is likely to depend on the specifics of the product so, as always, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).